# How to list available packages in a specific repository on Debian?

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management

Is it possible to list available packages in a specific repository, one of the repositories configured in `apt`, on Debian Jessie using the command line?

For example,

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free
```

from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: try apt-cache command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that the repository you're interested in is in your `apt` sources, you can find the information on the packages available there in the files `apt` downloads; for the line

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free
```

these would be respectively

- `/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages`
- `/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.de.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages`

(assuming you're on `amd64`). You can ensure those files are up-to-date first by running

```
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 6):

Aptitude can search by archive name:

```
aptitude search '~Ajessie'
```

`~A`*archive* (or, equivalently `?archive(`*archive*`)`) is documented in the [search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) as

> Select packages from the given archive (such as “unstable”).

If you want only the package names, then pass `-F %p` to format the output appropriately; by default you'll also get status and short description for each package.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz -O jessie.main.binary-amd64.Packages.gz

wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages.gz -O jessie.non-free.binary-amd64.Packages.gz
```

Followed by

```
gunzip jessie.main.binary-amd64.Packages.gz jessie.non-free.binary-amd64.Packages.gz
```

This will give you two files called `jessie.main.binary-amd64.Packages` and `jessie.non-free.binary-amd64.Packages`, which will jointly contain a list of packages corresponding to the source line

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free
```

As Stephen noted, if the sources entry is in your `sources.list`, then these files, along with many others, will be automatically downloaded to your disk, along with many others.

Comment: If `apt-get update` has been run after adding the source line, you might be able to use the existing files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.